# Can't enable/use URL rewriting on OS X Server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, osx-server

I am currently trying to install an issue-tracker on a Mac OS X Server but cant go further than the index page, because every subpage is only giving me 404 Not Found errors (The requested URL was not found on this server).

It seems like mod_rewrite isn't working properly.

I am loading the rewrite_module and set AllowOverride to All in /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf as well as in /Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf because this file is used instead of the first one when the Server App is installed. But it is still not working.

The Rewrite Engine in my .htaccess-file is set to "On", but it seems like apache isn't looking at that file at all.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.3 Server, Apache 2.2.22 and PHP 5.3.15 and the website's data is under /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default if that helps.

Am I missing something out? I'd appreciate any help or hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i solved it by myself - i had to add a new directory entry for the folder the issue tracker was installed in in the https_server_app.conf like this

```
<Directory "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Default/myissuetracker">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and in the .htaccess file i just commented out the "RewriteRule .* - [L]" and everything worked fine!

Comment: Thanks for this... installed Yosemite server (don't waste your $20) and had this issue crop up outta nowhere